# Trying to unstack dataframe with multiple empty columns (NaN)

Tags: python, pandas

I currently have a code which turns this:

```
       A     B    C  D    E  F    G  H    I  J
0  1.1.1  amba   50  1  131  4   40  3  150  5
1  2.2.2  erto   50  7   40  8  150  8  131  2
2  3.3.3  gema  131  2  150  5   40  1   50  3
```

Into this:

```
      ID  User  40  50  131  150
0  1.1.1  amba   3   1    4    5
1  2.2.2  erto   8   7    2    8
2  3.3.3  gema   1   3    2    5
```

And here you can check the code:

```
import pandas as pd
import io

df1 = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("""  A       B       C      D      E      F      G      H      I       J     
1.1.1   amba     50      1     131     4      40       3       150       5   
2.2.2   erto     50      7     40      8      150      8       131       2
3.3.3   gema     131     2    150      5      40       1        50       3"""), sep="\s+")



print(df1)


df2 = (pd.concat([df1.drop(columns=["C","D","E","F","G","H"]).rename(columns={"I":"key","J":"val"}),
           df1.drop(columns=["C","D","E","F","I","J"]).rename(columns={"G":"key","H":"val"}),
           df1.drop(columns=["C","D","G","H","I","J"]).rename(columns={"E":"key","F":"val"}),
           df1.drop(columns=["E","F","G","H","I","J"]).rename(columns={"C":"key","D":"val"}),
          ])      
 .rename(columns={"A":"ID","B":"User"})
 .set_index(["ID","User","key"])
 .unstack(2)
 .reset_index()
)

# flatten the columns..
df2.columns = [c[1] if c[0]=="val" else c[0] for c in df2.columns.to_flat_index()]
df2
```

The program works correctly if Key colums have unique values but it fails if there are duplicate values. The issue I have is that my actual dataframe has rows with 30 clumns, other with 60, other with 63, etc. So the program is detecting empty values as duplicate and the program fails.

Please check this example:

```
       A     B    C  D    E  F      G    H      I    J
0  1.1.1  amba   50  1  131  4    NaN  NaN    NaN  NaN
1  2.2.2  erto   50  7   40  8  150.0  8.0  131.0  2.0
2  3.3.3  gema  131  2  150  5   40.0  1.0   50.0  3.0
```

And I would like to get something like this:

```
      ID  User  40  50  131  150
0  1.1.1  amba       1    4    
1  2.2.2  erto   8   7    2    8
2  3.3.3  gema   1   3    2    5
```

If I try to unstack this, i get the error "Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape". I have been reading about this and df.drop_duplicates, pivot_tables, tc could help in this situation but I cannot just make work anything of this with my current code. Any idea about how o fix this? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Idea is convert first 2 columns to `MultiIndex`, then use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) by selected pair and unpair columns by [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html), reshaped by [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) and removed third unnecessary level of `MultiIndex` by [`DataFrame.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
df = df.set_index(['A','B'])
df = pd.concat([df.iloc[:, ::2].stack().reset_index(level=2, drop=True),
               df.iloc[:, 1::2].stack().reset_index(level=2, drop=True)], 
               axis=1, keys=('key','val'))
```

Last add `key` column to `MultiIndex` by [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) and reshape by [`Series.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html), convert `MultiIndex` to columns by `reset_index`, rename columns names and last remove columns levels name by  [`DataFrame.rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html):

```
df = (df.set_index('key', append=True)['val']
        .unstack()
        .reset_index()
        .rename(columns={"A":"ID","B":"User"})
        .rename_axis(None, axis=1))
print (df)
      ID  User  40  50  131  150
0  1.1.1  amba   3   1    4    5
1  2.2.2  erto   8   7    2    8
2  3.3.3  gema   1   3    2    5
```

Also it working well for second example, because missing rows are removed by `stack`, also added `rename` for convert columns names to `int` if possible:

```
df = df.set_index(['A','B'])
df = pd.concat([df.iloc[:, ::2].stack().reset_index(level=2, drop=True),
               df.iloc[:, 1::2].stack().reset_index(level=2, drop=True)], 
               axis=1, keys=('key','val'))


print (df)
              key  val
A     B               
1.1.1 amba   50.0  1.0
      amba  131.0  4.0
2.2.2 erto   50.0  7.0
      erto   40.0  8.0
      erto  150.0  8.0
      erto  131.0  2.0
3.3.3 gema  131.0  2.0
      gema  150.0  5.0
      gema   40.0  1.0
      gema   50.0  3.0


df = (df.set_index('key', append=True)['val']
        .unstack()
        .rename(columns=int)
        .reset_index()
        .rename(columns={"A":"ID","B":"User"})
        .rename_axis(None, axis=1))
print (df)
      ID  User   40   50  131  150
0  1.1.1  amba  NaN  1.0  4.0  NaN
1  2.2.2  erto  8.0  7.0  2.0  8.0
2  3.3.3  gema  1.0  3.0  2.0  5.0
```

EDIT1 Added helper column with counter for avoid duplicates:

```
print (df)
       A     B    C  D    E  F    G  H    I  J
0  1.1.1  amba   50  1   50  4   40  3  150  5 <- E=50
1  2.2.2  erto   50  7   40  8  150  8  131  2
2  3.3.3  gema  131  2  150  5   40  1   50  3

df = df.set_index(['A','B'])
df = pd.concat([df.iloc[:, ::2].stack().reset_index(level=2, drop=True),
               df.iloc[:, 1::2].stack().reset_index(level=2, drop=True)], 
               axis=1, keys=('key','val'))

df['g'] = df.groupby(['A','B','key']).cumcount()
print (df)
            key  val  g
A     B                
1.1.1 amba   50    1  0
      amba   50    4  1
      amba   40    3  0
      amba  150    5  0
2.2.2 erto   50    7  0
      erto   40    8  0
      erto  150    8  0
      erto  131    2  0
3.3.3 gema  131    2  0
      gema  150    5  0
      gema   40    1  0
      gema   50    3  0
```

---

```
df = (df.set_index(['g','key'], append=True)['val']
        .unstack()
        .reset_index()
        .rename(columns={"A":"ID","B":"User"})
        .rename_axis(None, axis=1))
print (df)
      ID  User  g   40   50  131  150
0  1.1.1  amba  0  3.0  1.0  NaN  5.0
1  1.1.1  amba  1  NaN  4.0  NaN  NaN
2  2.2.2  erto  0  8.0  7.0  2.0  8.0
3  3.3.3  gema  0  1.0  3.0  2.0  5.0
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do seems too complex. May i suggest a simpler solution which just converts each row to a dictionary of desired result and then binds them back together:

```
pd.DataFrame(list(map(lambda row: {'ID':row['A'], 'User':row['B'], row['C']:row['D'],
                               row['E']:row['F'], row['G']:row['H'], row['I']:row['J']}, 
                  df1.to_dict('r'))))
```