# Pandas - move values of a column under another column

Tags: python, pandas, multiple-columns

So here is my problem.

I'm using pandas to parse csv file.

So my csv file looks like this :

```
A   B   C   D
1   x   5   e
2   y   6   f
3   z   7   g
```

What I want to get is :

1. get all the values of column C
2. Place them under column A
3. Same with columns D and B

So it would get me this :

```
A   B   C   D
1   x       
2   y       
3   z      
5   e
6   f
7   g
```

However, all i've been able to get is to create a new column that "sums" column A with column C and column B with column D:

```
A   B   C   D   E   F
1   x   5   e   15  xe
2   y   6   f   26  yf
3   z   7   g   37  zg
```

Any idea would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Trying to unstack dataframe with multiple empty columns (NaN)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63950755/trying-to-unstack-dataframe-with-multiple-empty-columns-nan)

Answer (score 3):

Rename column `C` and `D` and append them to the bottom of columns `A` and B`:

```
result = df[['A', 'B']].append(df[['C','D']].set_axis(['A', 'B'], axis=1)).reset_index(drop=True)
```